# Subclassing with type that has name collisions

Tags: ios, swift, namespaces

Lets say I have a framework `Foo` that defined an open class `AwesomeType`. I embed that framework in my project, which unfortunately has a class named `AwesomeType`, too.

I read in in multiple places that Swift has implicit namespacing and that I can have the explicit name by just appending the framework's name. In my case that would be `Foo.AwesomeType`. That seems to work for instances of `Foo.AwesomeType`, but not for subclassing.

When I try to do

```
import Foo

public class Subclass: Foo.AwesomeType {
}
```

I get an error saying that `AwesomeType` is not a member type of `Foo`. When I leave out `Foo`, it will be referenced to the `AwesomeTyp` in my project, instead of that of the framwork.

How do I specify the correct type here?

Comment: I think I've seen this before, where if the library `Foo` contains some class also called `Foo`, then when you try to subclass using `Foo` as the name of the library, it thinks you're trying to use `Foo` as the name of the type. Is that the case here? Does the `Foo` library have a type called `Foo`?

Comment: It does indeed! Is there any workaround for that other than renaming that the type `Foo`? I guess I could also rename the framework's name?

Comment: Maybe a typealias could help somehow? Like maybe `typealias FooAwesomeType = Foo.AwesomeType`? Or maybe it would still pick it up as a type instead of the framework name... Worth a try though eh?

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help. I suppose the quickest way is to rename the framework. `FooKit`! You can create an answer and I'll accept it, as soon as I am allowed to.

Comment: Ahh, that's too bad! Yeah I guess renaming the framework is the best you can do, if you can. Seems like an oversight in Swift.

Comment: `import class Foo.AwesomeType` solves the problem.

Comment: Dang. This is golden `import (class|struct|func|protocol|enum) Module.Symbol`. Thanks @MikeTaverne